# Many Small SQL Error Logs

Tags: sql-server, error-log

I am looking at my SQL Server error logs and noticed that they cycle frequently.  Even though the files are small, some are only around 250 lines, they often cycle a number of times per day. This limits the range of time covered by the retained logs.

In the *Configure SQL Server Error Logs* screen, the size of the file is not limited, and I do not have an agent job that is recycling the logs.  I am also not in the habit of restarting the server several times per day.  Any information you can provide to help me track down the cause would be most appreciated.

From what I can see, it doesn't seem to be a restart.  Each of the queries below returns a datetime that is within 4 seconds of one another on a date in March when we had our system maintenance:

```
SELECT sqlserver_start_time FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info
SELECT login_time FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE session_id = 1
SELECT create_date FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'tempdb'
```

Answer (score 0):

A new error log is created every time the instance is restarted. This [is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/scm-services-configure-sql-server-error-logs?source=recommendations&view=sql-server-ver16) [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/viewing-the-sql-server-error-log?view=sql-server-ver16) [in a number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-cycle-errorlog-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks) of places.

As to why you have so many logs: clearly your instance is restarting often. Why that is so is unclear, but most likely you are using a User Instance or you have LocalDb, both of which will automatically shutdown some time after the last connection closes.

Another possibility is that the whole server is shuting down. Again you will have to investigate the cause.

---

It is obviously also possible that some tool or script that you have set up is running [`sp_cycle_errorlog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-cycle-errorlog-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), but that would not be the normal setup and you would need to investigate your own installation.

Comment: I put together trace in SQL Profiler and it looks like the Idera SQL Diagnostic Manager Collection Service is what is frequently cycling the logs.  I'll have to reach out to them to see just what is going on.